# error in running ansible-playbook with jenkins

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, jenkins

--i have a ansible playbook in ubuntu user   and  i am able to push this playbook in the remote user

-- now i have install jenkins in this ubuntu(EC2 instance) server , and i have given jenkins all sudo permission (jenins )[jenkins  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL]

--now from jenkins home account i can do ( sudo su - ubuntu )

--now in the jenkins  user interface  under  Build i have written bash command  **ansible-playbook deploy.yml** but i got ssh connection failer

-- i feel like jenkins running this command from his home account that's why ssh error occur

-- so under build  section i did

```
  whoami                    output  --jenkins
  sudo su - ubuntu          (from jenkins home account i am able to run this command )
  whoami                     output    -- still  jenkins
```

--  so i went to the **/etc/defauls/jenkins** file
sudo vi /etc/default/jenkins
$JENKINS_USER="ubuntu"
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/lib/jenkins
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/log/jenkins
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/cache/jenkins
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/run/jenkins

but now systemctl restart jenkins   now working ,  now service is not starting

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you installed Jenkins, but if you used `apt-get`, this means that your Jenkins daemon is most likely being started using the user `jenkins`.

You can check using `sudo grep JENKINS_USER /etc/sysconfig/jenkins`.

And since you changed all your Jenkins folders' ownership to user and group `ubuntu`, jenkins user will not be able to access the files.

I suggest you change the ownership back to user `jenkins` and then run your Ansible playbooks using `jenkins` user as well.